# How to create a chat activity in which mine message will be on right and other message on left

Tags: android, android-listview, chat

I am gonna exchange messages through api.

When i press send button to get message in list view it shows error null pointer exception in Messagelistadapter class in android;

Please help me its very important for me.

here is my code....

```
public class MessagelistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

TextView Name_from;
TextView text_message;
Context context;
List<Message> message_items;

public MessagelistAdapter(Context context, List<Message> message_items) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.message_items= message_items;

}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return message_items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return message_items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parentView) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Message message =message_items.get(position);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(message.getSelf())
    {
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_right, null);
        Name_from = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg_sender);
        text_message= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);

        Name_from.setText(message.getfromName().toString());
        text_message.setText(message.getmessage());
    }else
    {
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_msg_left, null);
        Name_from = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg_sender);
        text_message= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);

        Name_from.setText(message.getfromName());
        text_message.setText(message.getmessage());
    }



    return view;
}
```

}

```
public class Chat_activity extends FragmentActivity {

ActionBar actionBar;
EditText input_message;
Button btn_send;
ListView listview_messages;
MessagelistAdapter messagelistAdapter;
List<Message> message_list;
String name = "You";
String fromName, message,messgae_fromedittext;




private final static String TAG_SELF= "self", TAG_NEW = "new", TAG_MESSAGE="message", TAG_EXIT= "exit";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_activity);
    Bundle bd = getIntent().getExtras();

    String ticketid = bd.getString("TicketID");
    String problem = bd.getString("problem");

    actionBar =  getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(ticketid);
    actionBar.setSubtitle(problem);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    input_message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_message);
    listview_messages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);


    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            messgae_fromedittext =input_message.getText().toString();



            input_message.setText("");
            message = messgae_fromedittext;
            fromName = "You";
            boolean isSelf =true ;
            System.out.println(message+"       "+fromName+"           "+isSelf);

            Message messag= new Message(fromName, message, isSelf);
            appendMessage(messag);

        }
    });


    message_list = new ArrayList<Message>();

    messagelistAdapter = new MessagelistAdapter(this, message_list);
    listview_messages.setAdapter(messagelistAdapter);



}


private void appendMessage(final Message m)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            message_list.add(m);
            messagelistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public class Message {

String fromName, message;
private boolean isSelf;


public Message(){}

public Message(String fromName, String message, boolean isSelf)
{

    this.fromName=fromName;
    this.message=message;
    this.isSelf=isSelf;


}


public String getfromName()
{

    return fromName;
}


public void setfromName(String fromName)
{
        this.fromName = fromName;
}



public String getmessage()
{
    return message;
}

public void setmessage(String message)
{
    this.message = message;
}

public boolean getSelf()
    {

        return isSelf;

    }

public void setSelf(boolean isSelf)
{
    this.isSelf=isSelf;
}
```

}

here is my logcat

```
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at com.xsinfosol.helpdesk_customer.MessagelistAdapter.getView(MessagelistAdapter.java:67)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:709)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1636)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1977)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1731)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5498)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
12-31 17:22:43.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16756):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At which line you are getting error? Post logcat error.

Comment: @RockStar 67 line in MEssagelistadapter class

Comment: @RockStar  MessagelistAdapter extends BaseAdapter this class.

Comment: You need to post your logcat output, and point out which exact line the Exception is occurring on. You'll notice that there are no line numbers in the code you post.

Comment: @MikeM. i have added logcat.


this is the line in first class
Name_from.setText(message.getfromName().toString());

Comment: Well, then either `Name_from`, or the value returned from `message.getfromName()` is null. You'll have to work out which it is.

Comment: @MikeM. I have checked both are returning exact value despite getting same error.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. With the information given, it's pretty much got to be one of those two things. You're absolutely sure `Name_from != null`, and `message.getfromName() != null`, at that point in your code?

Comment: @MikeM. yes m pretty sure about that..

Comment: Pretty sure? Look at it this way: `message` isn't null, because you've already called `getSelf()` on it. The only other Objects in that line are the two mentioned. Check their values _immediately before_ that line.

Comment: @MikeM. yes I have checked....i have sysout to print values just before those lines in class